# Argb decoposition / recomposition issue

Tags: java, image, argb

```
public static int[] getIntARGB(int argb){
    int result[] = new int[4];
    result[0] = (argb & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    result[1] = (argb & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
    result[2] = (argb & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    result[3] = (argb & 0x000000FF);

    return result;
}
public static int getARBGInt(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
    return ((a << 24) | 0xFF) + ((r << 16) | 0xFF) + ((g << 8) | 0xFF) + (b | 0xFF);
}
```

Do you have any idea why if I take an argb int then decomposed it and repose it , it does not return the same value ?

One of this two (or both) function are messed up in a way but I don't know why (of course it would be stupid to just decompose and recompose the same argb value I want to modify if before but if there is a problem already I can't work x) )

Comment: you don't simply decompose and repose it. Think about what `| 0xFF` is doing and where you put those extra `1`s

Comment: Oh yeah thanks a lot why the hell I do that ><

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getARBGInt(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
    return (a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
}
```

I have accidentily put " | 0xFF " on the result of the `<< ...`

Comment: Glad you could solve your problem ;) You always learn more by finding the problem yourself than when someone else just gives you the right code!